# Connection between Class and primitive types?

Tags: java, class, language-concepts

I thought I understand concept of class(object) Class, but reading about it in Java API, I found this:

> The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long,
>   float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class
>   objects.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html   `The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE

Comment: What exactly you are wondering about? I meant, you don't get the point of object and class concept OR primitive type classes?

Comment: @NawaMan I guess it's primitive type classes. When I read quote above, I thought I misunderstood concept of Class. I didn't know connection of primitive types with Class.

Comment: @LazyLady I recommend you to revise the question to reflex that. :-D

Comment: @LazyLady did you read my answer with an example? Are you still interested? Feel free to ask about more details - I'll explain further if still needed.

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but I don't think that is my answer. I know what are autoboxing and outboxing. Maybe I just don't understand all of this - you can explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon on `autoboxing` and `unboxing` is what you're looking for. In java there are some primitives for comfort purposes. They all have `wrapper` classes. These are: `Integer`, `Double`, `Boolean` etc.

Autoboxing is responsible for wrapping `primitive`s into `Wrapper`s each time the `Wrapper` is expected but a `primitive` is passed. On the other hand unboxing comes. When it's a `primitive` expected but `Wrapper` passed unboxing will manage to extract the proper value.

It's well described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

**Example:**

```
Integer one = new Integer(1);
int i = one.intValue();

void printInteger(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

printInteger(one);
```

No exception will be thrown - `one` will be unboxed to `int` and printed.

Comment: This is not about Autoboxing. The classes Integer etc. were present from the beginning of Java on. Not only since Autoboxing was introduced.

Comment: @gsl I can agree that it's not **only** about autoboxing. As it was introduced to `java 1.5` we all use it.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is not looking for the autoboxing concept explanation.. rather they are baffled with the basic constructs of the language.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that the primitives are just zones of memory and when you are using the keyworks you are telling to compiler how 'to see' these areas. While with the correspondend objects such as Integer or Character are objects that have methods to work with these types and they are seen as such as objects